# ansible lvol module: volume not found

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'am feeling little bit idiot, I'am trying to delete vg and lvm from one serveur but I have message `"stdout": "Volume group vgdocker does not exist.", "stdout_lines": ["Volume group vgdocker does not exist."]}`

Please find below all info:

script:

```
- name: Remove the logical volume.
  lvol:
    vg: vgdocker
    lv: lvdocker
    state: absent
    force: yes
```

vgs

```
VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vgdocker   1   1   0 wz--n- <29.97g      0
```

lvs

```
 LV          VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lvdocker    vgdocker -wi-a----- <29.97g
```

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/mapper/vgdocker-lvdocker: 32.2 GB, 32178700288 bytes, 62849024 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Ansible Errors:

```
TASK [lv_remove : Remove the logical volume.] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [s00skb200] => {"changed": false, "stdout": "Volume group vgdocker does not exist.", "stdout_lines": ["Volume group vgdocker does not exist."]}
```

Comment: Is your playbook running with `--become`, or do you have `become: yes` on the playbook?

Comment: @mdaniel Can you post answer ? I will accept it.thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to run `ansible-playbook` using `--become`, or otherwise include the `become: yes` keyword in your playbook so the task will run with the elevated privileges required to interact with the device mapper

It's unfortunate that it came back with such a terrible error message, rather than saying "root is required"

Comment: Become: yes it is depreciated, now plese use **become: True**

Comment: deprecated in what way, since (a) [the docs clearly say `become: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/become.html#become-directives) and (b) yaml accepts both as boolean scalars?

Comment: my bad both are used.